# pread; threadsafe or not?

Tags: c, multithreading, posix

Is there a problem with using pread on the same file descriptor from 2 or more different threads at the same time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`pread` itself is thread-safe, since it is not on the [list of unsafe functions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_09.html#tag_02_09_01). So it is safe to call it.

The real question is: what happens if you read from the same file concurrently (not necessarily from two threads, but also from two processes).

Regarding this, the [specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pread.html) says:

- > The behavior of multiple concurrent reads on the same pipe, FIFO, or terminal device is unspecified.

  Note that it doesn't mention ordinary files. This bit relates only to `read` anyway, because `pread` cannot be used on unseekable files.
- > I/O is intended to be atomic to ordinary files and pipes and FIFOs.

  But this is from the non-normative section, so your OS might do it differently. E.g., if you read from two threads and there is a concurrent write, you might get different pieces of the write in your two read buffers. But this kind of problem is not specific to multithreading.

Also nice to know that in some cases

> read() shall block the calling thread

Not the process, just the thread. And

> A thread that has blocked shall not prevent any unblocked thread [...] from eventually making forward progress

Answer (score -1):

As we are using same fd, we have to bind a lock otherwise there will be mix of data from the two pread on the file descriptor.
Hence yes there is a problem in doing this

http://linux.die.net/man/2/pread

Comment: This answer is wrong. The whole purpose of `pread` is that you specify the position you want to read from, and position changes resulting from other threads/processes will not affect your read. Note that this only works on ordinary files and perhaps other seekable devices, not pipes/ttys/sockets/etc.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not 100% sure but I think that the file descriptor structure itself isn't thread safe, so two concurrent changes to it would corrupt it. You need some kind of locking.

Comment: There is no structure to corrupt on the application side, the file descriptor is just a number.

Comment: It's actually an index in a table with a data structure. Who changes the table? The C runtime or the kernel? If the C runtime updates the current file offset, it's unsafe. If it's the kernel, then it might be thread safe.

Comment: The file descriptor table is in the kernel and the C runtime does not have access to it.  Of course the kernel code has to be thread-safe.